# Quelle est la différence entre cueillir et récolter ?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot

Les dictionnaires disent que ce sont des synonymes, alors quelle est la différence entre ces deux mots ?

Answer (score 7):

*S'il s'agit d'agriculture*

> - CUEILLIR : détacher (une partie d'un végétal) de la tige, des racines.

Cueillir est un geste technique très précis : on détache un fruit d'un arbre, on cueille une fleur, tout cela manuellement, un par un (ou poignée par poignée).

> - RÉCOLTER : Faire la récolte de (qqch.)
> - RÉCOLTE : Action de recueillir (les produits de la terre)
> - RECUEILLIR : Prendre en cueillant ou en ramassant en vue de conserver pour utiliser ultérieurement, et aussi rassembler, réunir

Mais on récolte les olives en secouant l'olivier après avoir mis des filets pour récupérer les olives mûres, on ne saisit pas les olives une par une.

De même on fauche les céréales, car on coupe le plus possible de tiges à la fois en se servant d'engins agricoles.

Il y a donc l'action de cueillir plus l'action de réunir, de regrouper.
La *récolte* est le résultat de la *cueillette* (qu'elle soit manuelle ou mécanique).

N.B. : Les sens figurés gardent les mêmes notions, entre l'action d'attraper quelque chose ou quel qu'un et le résultat, souvent groupé, de ces actions successives :

- Se faire cueillir : on est pris au collet, on est pris en flagrant délit...
- Allez les cueillir à la descente du train : chaque personne sera accueilli à son arrivée à la gare
- Récolter le fruit de ses erreurs, fruit que l'on n'a pas du tout envie de cueillir, mais que l'on récolte comme résultat de ce que l'on a semé.

---

*<sup>Références extraites du petit Robert</sup>*

Answer (score 5):

Récolter implique une action de culture, que ce soit une culture de végétaux, ou bien une culture plus imagée

> Je récolte le fruit de mes efforts
>
> Nous avons récolté les haricots

Alors que cueillir serait plus utilisé dans le sens où l'on a cherché le fruit de la cueillette, mais on n'a pas spécialement attendu longtemps pour l'obtenir

> J'ai cueilli la cerise sur l'arbre
>
> Nous avons cueilli le fugitif en cavale lors d'un contrôle de routine

Answer (score 4):

Ces verbes dérivent de la même origine latine *colligere* qui a aussi donné collecter et collectionner. Il y a un recouvrement certain entre eux, mais il n'est pas total.

Au sens propre, cueillir est plus indiqué pour décrire le prélèvement "délicat" d'une fleur, d'un fruit, d'un fruit ou d'un brin d'herbe, souvent entre deux doigts; récolter s'applique en revanche au prélèvement quantitatif de végétaux qui ont le plus souvent été semés ou plantés dans le but de produire de la nourriture ou des matières premières, ou le prélèvement de tout produit naturel ou non, dans une acception plus large.

On peut donc cueillir pour le plaisir des fleurs et des fruits sauvages alors que l'on récolte fruits, légumes et autres végétaux semés ou plantés à cet effet.

On dira rarement « cueillir des pommes de terre » mais plutôt « récolter des pommes de terre ». Inversement, on ne récolte pas **une** fleur mais on la cueille. Dès qu'il y en a plusieurs, les deux se rencontrent: on cueille ou on récolte des fleurs de jasmin, le tournesol, la lavande, etc.

Comment: La *récolte* du goémon (qui n'a ni été planté ni semé) se fait par des cueilleurs (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varech ) -- On parle de *récolte* du Jasmin à Grasse (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jasmin ) récolte faite de fleurs *cueillies* à la main.

Comment: @cl-r J'aurais mis *récolte du goémon* dans l'acception de récolter au sens figuré mais le tlfi indique « par analogie ». J'ai modifié ma réponse pour tenir compte de ces commentaires, merci !

Answer (score 2):

#### Cueillir / La cueillette

On laisse la plante sur place, on ne touche qu'aux légumes, baies, fruits, ...

- Je suis allé dans mon verger afin d'y **cueillir** quelques pommes bien mûres.
- Lors de **la cueillette** des champignons il est conseillé de ne pas ôter les racines du sol. Ceci afin de ne pas compromettre la cueillette de l'an prochain.

#### Récolter / La récolte :

On va récupérer le résultat de la culture mais la plante sera détruite/altérée par le processus.

- **Récolter** les patates est fastidieux car il faut retourner la terre avec une fourche.
- Une fois le champ fauché, nous savions la **récolte** du blé sur le point de s'achever.

Answer (score 2):

La réponse complète a déjà été donnée par cl-r.

En ce qui concerne la connotation des termes, que "cueillir" est plus souvent plus délicat, on cueille une fleur, on la détache délicatement de sa tige, et récolter, c'est souvent dans le cadre d'un travail de récolte, à plus grande échelle. C'est un travail physique beaucoup moins délicat, on se baisse, on se donne du mal.

> Hier, je me suis amusée à cueillir des fleurs sur le bord de la route,
>   en me promenant.
>
> Je regardais les paysans récolter le blé, ce qui faisait suer leur
>   visage.

(On a là une idée de quelques fleurs, et beaucoup de blé, en plus de l'idée de pénibilité).

On peut aussi cueillir des fruits pour les manger, mais quand on dit, "récolter des fruits" au lieu de "cueillir", on introduit une notion supérieure de travail et de quantité.

> Je cueille quelques fruits pour faire une tarte.
>
> Mon oncle et ma tante ont passé 3 jours à faire la récolte de leurs
>   pommiers.

La personne qui mentionne une idée de "culture" (donc un travail) a tout fait raison. On récolte ce qu'on a semé au préalable en général, que ce soit au sens propre (des céréales) ou imagé (les conséquences de ses actions). Mais on peut tout de même faire une récolte sur une parcelle sauvage je pense que s'il y a l'idée de travail intensif, ça peut tout à fait se dire:

> Je récolte des amandes sauvages.

(travail, quantité)

Answer (score 0):

Pour moi cueillir c'est du domaine de l’alimentaire, alors que récolter est un terme plus générique.

Dans les jeux vidéos par exemple, on parle de récolter des objets.
La récolte c'est le fait de récupérer quelques chose "par terre", alors que cueillir c'est vis à vis d'un végétal dans un but alimentaire.

Comment: Mangez-donc ces fleurs que je viens de cueillir pour vous ! ;-)

Comment: Oui le alimentaire est optionnel, c'est vrai XD mais ça reste bien végétal.

Comment: Je ne suis pas tout à fait d'accord avec ton interprétation. Attention, le terme "récolter" pour l'appliquer aux objets, est une sorte de jargon de jeux vidéos, c'est de l'anglais directement traduit. On dirait "cueillir des objets" si les objets que tu avais à collectionner dans ton jeu se trouvaient en hauteur par exemple.

Comment: Non mais il n'y a pas que les jeux vidéos. On parle de récolter des parrainages ou des avis, pas de les cueillir... Cueillir est un dérivé de la brique récolter, plus générique.

Comment: Ça ferait une excellente question sans doute, _quel verbe est le plus usuel pour signifier dans un jeu (vidéo) l'activité dont le résultat est d'avoir une grande quantité d'objets dans son inventaire_. @PERCE-NEIGE De quel terme anglais dites-vous que _récolter_ provienne ? Merci.

Comment: En anglais on parle de "farm des objets" / "farming" qui correspond à "cultiver"...

Comment: Merci ! _Farming for objects_, ça implique quoi au juste, d'aller vaincre des adversaires pour ensuite s'emparer de leur butin ? En quoi ça diffère de _questing for experience_ alors qu'incidemment on aura aussi droit au butin ? Bien intéressant, c'est cependant hors sujet mais pas la question du verbe.

Comment: oui, dans beaucoup de jeu, en tuant un monstre tu as un butin. C'est possible aussi en faisant des quêtes...

Comment: @Matrix, Dans ce cas récolter = engranger. Mettre dans une sorte de petit panier virtuel en quelque sorte. Mais quand on "récolte des signatures", c'est un peu différent du fait de "récolter un objet" dans un sens vidéo, pas la place pour développer. Farming, c'est même plus que récolter, ça veut dire faire des actions répétitives, pour gagner automatiquement des points. Il y a bien le concept de faire de "l'élevage". Engraisser le cochon. Oui, c'est assez hors-sujet.